# Saving current timestamp in mySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

I am doing a project in Java. On hospital management. In which I designed a form which store patient information wiht uniqe registration number. Now I come to problem, its that I want to store all his visits with current date and time. So that when I open its record it should show me all its visits with date. So suggest me a method to store such date in database. How should I store its every visit currosponding to his uniqID number and also fetch all of his visiting dates. I am using mysql 5.1 server.

Comment: What did you try? Did you read the MySQL documentation on Dates and Times?

Answer (score 0):

Create a table that will store data for every visit. One of the columns in this table should be a 'DATETIME' type and then use the funciton NOW in order to populate it.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now

```
CREATE TABLE `visits` (
`uniqID` INT NOT NULL ,
`visit_time` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
INDEX ( `uniqID` )
);
```

To populate run this

```
INSERT INTO visits SET uniqID = '{user_uniqID }', visit_time = NOW();
```

To get user visit, showing the most recent on the top.

```
SELECT * FROM visits WHERE uniqID = '{user_uniqID }' ORDER BY visit_time DESC;
```